# Is 5.4 to 5.5 volts ok for WS 2812B Led Matrix?

Tags: ws2812b

I tried buying a cheap LED power supply ALIDOVE BRAND. I checked the voltage without/with Arduino and the LED matrix connected.
It's always 5.5 volts but it's working in its intended purpose - a clock (tried it only for 4 sec for fear of destroying the LED). Will it not damage the LED WS2812B matrix?
I'm asking this question because of conflicting info on the net and I cant find a reliable info.

Comment: What does the datasheet for the WS2812B say its input voltage range is?

Comment: *I tried buying* yeah that never succeed.

Comment: You need to find the spec for *your* LED matrix. Some are only rated up to 5.3 V. It isn't that hard to make a power supply with +/-5% tolerance. I suspect that they set the voltage a little high intentionally to satisfy inexperienced customers who tend to undersize their wires.

Comment: Only the cheap one in aliexpress, so theres little info there. Read the reviews on alitove power supply , about voltage not even 5 volts previously so maybe they make it so much higher..

Comment: you can put a schottkey diode in series with VCC to shave off about 350mv. it should be fine though, even if cheap crap. Are you sure the power supply is at 5.5v under load? Many are a tad higher open-circuit than when actually doing stuff.

Comment: Its 5.37 volt checked it again, probably misread the tester but its higher than 5v. The only thing i got exactly 5 volts is on power bank..Thanks for the answer i will do the schottkey diode to be sure. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The [spec sheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf) states "Electrical Characteristics（T A =-20～+70 ℃ ，**V DD =4.5～5.5V**,V SS =0V, unless otherwise specified).

The operating voltage limit is given as 5.3 V, but it's unlikely damage was done by an excess 0.2 VDC.

Comment: tried other 5volt power supply i have, they gave 5.3 volts W/O load so maybe 5 volts fixed is impossible.Anyway thanks..